# Why is csv.DictReader giving me a no attribute error?

Tags: python, csv

My CSV file is

```
200
Service
```

The code I'm putting into the interpreter is

```
snav = csv.DictReader(open("screennavigation.csv"), delimiter=',')
print snav.fieldnames
['200']

for line in snav:
...     print(line)
...
{'200': 'Service'}

snav["200"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: DictReader instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I thought that `DictReader` was meant to return a dictionary. I suspect I'm missing something brutally obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`snav` object is `DictReader` instance and shouldn't be accessed as a dictionary. On iteration it produces dictionaries that could be accessed accordingly: you need `line['200']`

Answer (score 4):

The `DictReader` produces a *list* of dictionaries. Each line is itself a dictionary - as you show when you iterate through in your for loop.

(OK, it's actually an iterable, not a list, but the point stands.)