# Collapse dictionary on key

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having issues reading a CSV into a dictionary and collapsing that dictionary by a key. I have enough code to get to this point (I have all the counties for each state):

```
{'County': '02013', 'State': 'Alaska', 'Rate': '28.38692673', 'Zip': '99553'}
{'County': '02013', 'State': 'Alaska', 'Rate': '28.38692673', 'Zip': '99571'}
{'County': '02013', 'State': 'Alaska', 'Rate': '28.38692673', 'Zip': '99583'}
{'County': '02013', 'State': 'Alaska', 'Rate': '28.38692673', 'Zip': '99612'}
```

But I would like the following result:

```
{'County': '02013', 'State': 'Alaska', 'Rate': '28.38692673', 'Zips': ['99553', '99571', '99583', '99612']}
```

My current python code is:

```
with open('../models/mock_data/geography_data.csv', 'r') as f:

result = {}
red = csv.DictReader(f)
```

I've attempted to add the following:

```
for d in red:
    result.setdefault(d["County"], [d["State"], d["Rate"]]).append(d["Zip"])
```

But that results in data like the following (missing keys)

```
16079': ['Idaho', '21.02970297', '83802', '83808', '83812', '83837', '83839', '83846', '83849', '83850', '83867', '83868', '83873', '83874']
```

There are plenty of other questions similar to this one using `iteritems()` and `setdefaultdict()` (like this one: [How should I collapse elements in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386566/how-should-i-collapse-elements-in-python)) but I suppose I'm not understanding those processes enough to implement them in my particular case. Any and all help is welcome.

--update--

Ok so @timegb helped me quite a bit but I was most comfortable using a brute force approach:

```
with open('../models/mock_data/all_geo_data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    dicts = [dict(zip(header, map(str,row))) for row in reader]

    counties = []
    result = []

    for i in dicts:
        zips = []
        if i["County"] not in counties:
            counties.append(i["County"])
            zips.append(i["Zip"])
            temp_dict = {"County": i["County"], "State" : i["State"], "Zip" : zips, "Rate" : i["Median_CNC_Labor_Rate"] }
            result.append(temp_dict)

    for i in dicts:
        for j in result:
            if i["County"] == j["County"] and i["Zip"] not in j["Zip"]:
            j["Zip"].append(i["Zip"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> with open('testfile') as f:
...     dicts = [literal_eval(line) for line in list(f)]
...     result = {'Zips':[d['Zip'] for d in dicts]}
...     result.update(dicts[0])
...     del result['Zip']
...     del dicts
... 
>>> result
{'Zips': ['99553', '99571', '99583', '99612'], 'County': '02013', 'State': 'Alaska', 'Rate': '28.38692673'}
```

We `literal_eval` all lines in your file. The result is the first dictionary with the value of the key 'Zips' set to a list of the zip-values from all dictionaries. If you don't need the other dictionaries, you can issue `del dicts` at the end.

*update*

It seems you already have a list of dictionaries from reading your csv file, which I will call `dicts`. In that case, the code simplifies itself so:

```
result = {'Zips':[d['Zip'] for d in dicts]}
result.update(dicts[0])
del result['Zip']
```

Comment: I am receiving a malformed string error. I don't exactly understand it because I don't believe there's anything in the data that could have caused it. Do you think it's Python 2.7 vs. Python 3 issue?

Comment: @wsankey Sorry I cant reproduce the error. I copy-pasted your data into my testfile. I tested the code in Python2 and Python3 and it works in both. Most likely your input file is corrupted/malformed. Did you try creating a new input file by copy pasting the one you provided here?

Comment: @wsankey Or is the first four lines you provided not your input file? In that case, the answer is easier and we can leave the whole file I/O out, I just need to know whether you have your existing dictionaries in any collection or how they are stored.

Comment: Sorry, for not being explicit. I received those lines by running the following code and copying and pasting the output from the DictReader. They are not my input. I have a CSV as input. Also, I striped out an empty key that was just appearing in my list of dictionaries. I thought if I could remove that it would fix the issue and your code would work.              red = csv.DictReader(f)
 for row in red:
  print row

Comment: Alright. In that case, just append your dictionaries to a list `dicts` while reading them in. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is so close that I will accept it as correct although I'm not getting exactly the answer. The problem is that the csv.DictReader does not produce a list of dictionaries exactly, it looks like it's an iterable (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865622/why-is-csv-dictreader-giving-me-a-no-attribute-error) once I make it a list of dictionaries this will work. I tried to just do:  dictob = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")
 dicts = list(dictob) but that gives me all zipcodes on the first county. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hrm, all the zip codes in the county are still attaching themselves to the first county even after I create a list of dictionaries using your update. Here is the full code after the with(open( statement:                                     reader = csv.reader(f)
 header = next(reader)
 dicts = [dict(zip(header, map(str,row))) for row in reader]
 result = {'Zips':[d['Zip'] for d in dicts]}
 result.update(dicts[0])
 del result['Zip']
 print result

Comment: @wsankey I think it would be best if you open a new question and include your input file, then we can approach the problem from the start. It's hard to discuss code in the comment section because of the lack of formatting.

Comment: @timeb thank you for the note, and yes I agree. I actually used a brute force method that I'll post as an edit to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Try thus

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('your_file_name') as sub: 
array = [literal_eval(line) for line in list(sub)]
sol_n = {'time':[each['time'] for each in array]}
sol_n.update(array[0])
del sol_n['time']
del dicts
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: wow, no disrespect but it answer the question. At least it is something. no need for the hostility.

Comment: It is no hostility or disrespect. I did not say that it is not an answer. It is only a recommendation on how you can improve your answers.

Comment: It was misunderstanding on my part, sorry. I will try to improve the answer as suggested. thanks